# Flutter Web: persist state when navigating to a new Url

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

When navigating to a new URL (or refreshing the page) I see my whole state being recreated. At least in the case of navigating to a new URL route, I would assume to use the state previously loaded. This is my app

```
runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AppState()),
      ],
      child: FlutterWebFrame(
          builder: (context) => MaterialApp.router(
              routeInformationParser: AppRouteInformationParser(),
              routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(
                  context.watch<AppState>()
              ),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              backButtonDispatcher: RootBackButtonDispatcher(),
            ),
          maximumSize: Size(475.0, 812.0), // Maximum size
          enabled: kIsWeb,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

and these are the relevant parts of `AppState` and `AppRouterDelegate`

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {

  AppState() {
    print("creating app state");
  }

  bool loadingDone = false;

  void setLoadingDone() {
    loadingDone = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<AppRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<AppRoutePath> {

  final AppState appState;

  @override
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  AppRouterDelegate(this.appState) {
   print("created router delegate");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageStack;

    if (!appState.loadingDone) {
      pageStack = [
        _buildPage("Launch", LaunchWidget())
      ];
    } else {
      pageStack = [
        _buildPage("AvailableMatches", AvailableMatches()),
        if (appState.selectedMatch != null)
          _buildPage("MatchDetails", MatchDetails(matchId: appState.selectedMatch))
      ];
    }
    print("built stack with ${pageStack.length} pages");

    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: pageStack,
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }

        if (route.settings.name == "MatchDetails") {
          appState.setSelectedMatch(null);
        }
        return true;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

if I navigate to `/match/123` page or to `/` all the navigation logic works correctly but I see the prints called in the constructor of `AppState` and `AppRouterDelegate` which means the objects are recreated.

Since `AppState` is recreated I lose the value of `loadingDone` which gets reset to false and therefore I have to always pull all the data again (and the loading page is pushed into the Navigator stack again)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, on the web, when you refresh the page or enter a new URL in the browser's address bar, it restarts the app from scratch.

If you try to run this small code snippet:

```dart
void main() {
  print('In main');
  init();
  runApp(const SizedBox());
}

void init() {
  print('init');
}
```

When you start the app, you will see:

```
main
init
```

it you refresh the page, you will get the logs

```
main
init
main
init
```

This means `runApp` is run again, and it runs `init()` too so you will lose all your states since it is a brand new app execution.

If you want to keep the state, you will have to save it somewhere to be able to reuse it (like in the cache with `html.Storage` or [`hive`](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)).

Comment: is it supposed to do that? even when we change the URL? how come the state is reused then if normal navigation also rewrites the URL?

Comment: What do you mean "when we change the url" ? Is it you writting the URL in the address bar or using a method `.push` from a routing API ?

Comment: What do you mean "when we change the url" ? Is it you writting the URL in the address bar or using a method `.push` from a routing API ?

Comment: if I use the `.push` (or declarative state management) and the URL gets re-written by Flutter, why don't we lose state there?

Comment: There is a difference between doing `.push` and writing by hand the URL. When you are using `.push`, the flutter router communicates to the browser the new URL and you see it updated. But when you write the URL in the address bar or refresh, the browser kills the current app and starts a new one from the URL you entered.